# Find dependency not listed in app:dependencies task

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I have a dependency listed under the External Libraries folder of the Project view in Android Studio that I would like to find out who is pulling into the project.

But this dependency does not show in when I list the app's dependencies by executing `gradle app:dependencies` task.

I've tried running the *Analyze Backward Dependencies...* task available in the contextual menu of the External Libraries list, but it just never ends (possibly because this is a massive project).

There are no .aar nor .jar libraries added directly to the project, just dependencies added in the gradle files.

How can I find out where this external library is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that running the `app:dependencies` on a multi-module project would gather the dependencies of every subproject inside it but it seems that is not the case.

Adding the following line to the root `build.gradle` file

```
subprojects {
    task fullDependencies(type: DependencyReportTask) {}
}
```

By then running the `gradle fullDependencies` task I could find the offending dependency that was not listed in `app:dependencies`.